# Docker RabbitMQ runs then stops

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I am trying to follow this tutorial on setting up docker clusters https://levelup.gitconnected.com/setting-up-rabbitmq-cluster-c247d61385ed

I get to running the following command that I will need to run for the other two nodes

```
docker run -d --rm --net rabbit -v C:\RabbitPrototype\config\rabbit-1/:/config/ -e RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE=/config/rabbitmq -e RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE=ABCDYJLFQNTHDRZEPLOZ --hostname rabbit-1 --name rabbit-1 -p 8081:15672 rabbitmq:3.9-management
```

I can see it run in the docker graphical container view, but after a couple seconds it disappears, as seems that the container stops running, what do I need to do order to keep it running, are there any logs to look at to see why it stopped?

I have removed the **--rm** mentioned by @Omer

I get this error

```
2021-12-16 16:24:41.403174+00:00 [erro] <0.130.0> Failed to load advanced configuration file "/config/rabbitmq.config": 1: syntax error before: '.'
```

My config file that I am trying to load looks like this, copied from the tutorial page, so currently not sure what the issue is with the . (dot) between then users.guest part on line one?

```
loopback_users.guest = false
listeners.tcp.default = 5672
cluster_formation.peer_discovery_backend = rabbit_peer_discovery_classic_config
cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.1 = rabbit@rabbit-1
cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.2 = rabbit@rabbit-2
cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.3 = rabbit@rabbit-3
```

Comment: Try to get rid of the `--rm` flag to avoid the container being deleted after it stops, then you can inspect the logs to try and figure out what made it stop

Comment: Thanks that at least keeps it available and I get the error as updated above :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have something running with this command now running this, I renamed the rabbitmq.config to rabbitmq.conf and also told it to put it in the /etc/rabbitmq/ which seems to be the default location

```
docker run --net rabbit -v C:\\RabbitPrototype\config\rabbit-1\:/etc/rabbitmq/ -e RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE=ABCDYJLFQNTHDRZEPLOZ --hostname rabbit-1 --name rabbit-1 -p 8081:15672 rabbitmq:3.9-management
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue from the error message seems to be that RabbitMQ thinks you are providing it an advanced configuration file instead of the normal configuration file - https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#advanced-config-file . Even though since RabbitMQ 3.7+ has sysctl(the format you used) kind of configuration files, the advanced configuration file still uses the classic configuration format(https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#config-file-formats) which explains the syntax error.

From the docs - https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#configuration-files

Not sure why it would pick the value of the `RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE` as the advanced config file instead of the default one.

Can you update the question with the full logs? Even after the container is dead, you can check its logs using
`docker logs rabbit-1`